# Can one find out login and logout times on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Through any Facebook API, is there a way to

1. obtain the login/logout times for a user?
2. track when a user is logged in?

Basically, I want to calculate how long a user has been logged into Facebook for a Facebook application. I plan to program in PHP.

Comment: wow! extreme stalking + privacy violation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not get this data through Facebook directly.  The closest thing you could do was see the last time he was "active" aka posted something, changed something etc.